# How handle exception that value == None is ok and it should be passed?

Tags: python, exception

I get response as None and its ok, it is not error. But every time when I run program I get exception.

```
        response = None
        try:
            if ~self.session.is_active:
                self.session.rollback()

           data = self.session.query(Data)\
                               .filter(GeocoderData.address == address)
                                .first()
           response = data.yandex['response']
           logger.info(f"response = {str(e)}")

       except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
            self.db_session.rollback()
            self.error = messages["db_error"]
            logger.error(f"{str(e)}")

        return response
```

I try to make like this:

```
 if response or response == None:
```

in try block, bit it doesnt work

How I should handle case, that get response = None is ok, it is not exception?

Comment: Remove `try/except` and show us what error do you get. Btw what is a variable `e`? It's not declared anywhere

Comment: should be  except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:

Comment: I got KeyError: 'response'

Comment: That means object `data.yandex` doesn't have a field named `response`

Comment: response = data.yandex.get('response', None) Change that line to this. @try_to_code

Comment: `if ~self.session.is_active:` ? ... **`~`**?

Comment: the idea is that if I get value == None its ok,

Comment: but if it is another one, should return this value, not None

Comment: @K.Mat how to handle this case, could you advise?

Comment: Where you have written `~self.session.is_active`, what do you expect this to mean?

Comment: The exception **is not caused** by `response` being equal to `None`. It is caused by the attempt to use **the string** `'response'` as a key for the `data.yandex` dictionary. That has **nothing to do with** the variable named `response`. You **are not getting** a `None` value from the dictionary lookup. The dictionary lookup **is failing** because that key is **not present**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `KeyError: 'response'`, because there is no field named *response* in `data.yandex`. Instead of getting dictionary value by square brackets:

```py
data.yandes['response']
```

use getter, with specified default value

```py
data.yandes.get('response', None)
```

This way, if there is no field named 'response', it will return `None`.
The next thing to do, if you want the `None` response to be ok, but everything else bad, do:

```py
if response is not None:
    raise ValueError
```

This way, if your response return `None`, program goes normally, but if its anything else but `None`, an error is thrown, and your `except` clause is being run.